# How to model a NavigationStack in SwiftUI under iOS16 of a wizard view sequence?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-environment, ios16

**Scenario**
I have a wizard that all work on the same data object which is passed from step to step.

*Steps*:

1. Start
2. Some input values
3. Finish (draft becomes a actual db entry)

**Current solution**

Currently I use the old but working `NavigationLink(isActive: ...)`. Now, I try to port my app to the new SwiftUI alongside iOS 16. That means the "old" `NavigationLink` is outdated. I tried `NavigationStack` with or without a `$path`, etc. pp

**What's my actual problem?**

All examples or great answers on SO I found (also from Apple) are "too simple" - I guess. I do not have a list, my navigation is "next"-Button-based. My "Destination view" is not just a `TextField` and I do not have a strict navigation flow (in future, there will be optional steps in between) as in the WWDC22 sample.

A step (aka View) will be also used in another wizard, too. Is this a good idea?

**What I think, I need**

My "wizard container view" I call it "flow" which embeds all other steps has to have a `NavigationStack($path) {}` component.

I have to make the `path` isn e.g. an `EnvironmentObject` that I can easily access and modify it during my wizard run from each child view.

I need a mapping using `.navigationDestination(for: WizardNavigation.self) { switch ... }` to show the requested next step.

**But, what do I miss?**

It feels over complicated and, again, to strict in navigation. The parent has to know all possible navigation destinations?

Please tell me, that I miss a big point that simplifies my whole approach.

Comment: It is too wide, try to do some code and then show where you get problem, if any.

Comment: Btw, novigationDestination can be at any navigation level inside NavigationStack. And this one should be helpful for multi-data path usage https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestNavigationStackDynamicPath.swift.